# CGI Perl Echo back POSTed application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content

Tags: perl, cgi, mime-types

I need a simple CGI based Perl script to receive a POST (directly, not from another HTML page) with Content-Type being application/x-www-form-urlencoded and to echo back

I received: (encoded string)

(and if possible)
decoded, the string is: (decoded string)

I am new to CGI Perl, and this is a one off request for testing a product (I'm a sysadmin. not a programmer).  I intend to learn Perl more deeply in the future, but in this case I'm hoping for a gimme.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#SYNOPSIS is a good start for CGI.

Comment: "to receive a POST (directly, not from another HTML page)" — A POST request is a POST request. The server cares nothing about what caused the client to generate it unless your write code to explicitly examine the referrer (or you use something like an anti-CSRF nonce)

Answer (score 0):

To start off, I will quickly skim some of the basics.

Following is the package for PERL/CGI application:

```
use CGI;
```

To create CGI object:

```
my $web = CGI->new;
```

Make sure you set and then write HTTP headers to outstream,  before flushing out any CGI data to outstream. Otherwise you would end up in 500 error.

To set the headers:

```
print $web->header();
print $web->header('application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

To receive any post data from HTML,  say for example,

```
http://example.com?POSTDATA=helloworld
```

you may use param() function:

```
my $data = $web->param('POSTDATA');
```

scalar $data would be set with "helloworld".

It is advisable to check if $web->param('POSTDATA') is defined before you assign to a scalar.

Comment: `CGI` is *a* package for doing CGI in Perl. There are quite a few others, I'd use `Plack::Handler::CGI` as it is more flexible for when I escape CGI and use something decent. You don't want to be using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as the content type for the return data, that's the format the form will post it in, not something useful to send back to a browser. Your example provides the data as GET data, not POST.

Comment: I thought POSTDATA is specifically NOT for application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content.  The doc I read says that is the Content-Type is not urlencoded then the text will be captured in a param called POSTDATA.  What am I missing here?

Comment: @GreggLeventhal — You're right, I hadn't seen that before. That is, apparently, how you get the raw POST data in CGI.pm. Shame it doesn't use a sensible approach (like having a different method to call for it).